# May define model in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model

I have a document getting data from multiple form , and these form are added dynamically( like add more question ), what I actually want, want to define custom model to get data push in document and then save/update.

Sample Document

```
{
    id:1,
    paper:"ABC TEST",
    sections:[{
        section_name:"A",
        marks:10
        questions:[{
            question:"Question 1",
            answers:[{},...],
            answer_type:"mcq",
            },{}.....
            ]
    },....]
}
```

All I want to define there param in model to validate and populate/get data  from html
like

```
$scope.exam_model = {
    id:{type:"String"},
    paper:{type:"String"},
    sections:[{
        section_name:{type:"String"},
        marks:{type:"Number"},
        questions:[{
            question:{type:"String"},
            answers:[],
            answer_type:{type:"String"}

            ]
    }]
}
```

I am new in Angular , I have seen lots of tutorial and not found any model structure.

Comment: Please explain problem in more precise detail. It's not very clear what you are asking. How to create a schema? How to do validation?

Comment: I looks like you're trying to make your json object strongly-typed like XML when that really goes against its nature.